# Cloning multiple hard drives into one mass backup drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, disk-cloning

There are two computers I need to back up to one hard drive. The hard drive is big enough for both of their drives (one is another HDD, the other is an SSD). Both have only one internal drive.

How would I go about getting all the partitions off them? I imagine I couldn't keep the OSs running while taking all their files, would I need to use some sort of bootable USB tool that can copy the internal drive(s) to an external USB hard drive?

Nothing on the backup drive needs to be bootable or anything, so any special metadata partitions or anything that can't just be simply copied (I am not particularly knowledgable about the inner workings of booting, partitions et cetera) can be dropped if needed. It's about getting all the data in a big sweep and sifting through it later, on another machine.

I will also need to be able to continue to use the remaining empty space on the hard drive.

Comment: Clonezilla is one of the tools you could use. I've used it from a separate bootable environment 'ultimate boot cd'

Comment: Can't use just clone the physical disks to image files?

Comment: I boot a Linux system and abuse ddrescue  - Its easier to use then dd and gives you a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is with free third-part imaging software, such as [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or one of the [many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). Though I don't see the OS mentioned, it is irrelevant if you use one of those tools with USB "rescue" software.

For example, with *Macrium Reflect*, to create a single file with images of multiple HHD's and SSD's:

- If operating under Windows OS, simply install *Macrium Reflect*, start the application, select drives, and start backup. **This can be done even on a running, mounted partition**, using Windows *Volume Shadow Copy Service*, though it's preferable nothing else be running at that time.
- For Linux, and probably for any other OS running on the x86-64 bit platform, which have not implemented *Volume Shadow Copy*, boot from a partition that will *not* be included in the image.

  - Install *Macrium Reflect*, *if* it runs under *wine* [AFAIK, not yet working],
  - Or have someone with Windows PC install it.
  - Then use a USB drive of 8 GB or larger to make a bootable rescue drive.
  - Shut down the PC and boot from the USB drive (*Macrium Reflect* uses Win RE for the OS).
  - As above, select drives and start the backup.

Though these tools happily image any disk format, most cannot mount the ext4 Linux partitions directly from the image; you'd need a third-party tool if you want to mount them as virtual drives.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/).

You would create a partition on the backup drive that is big enough to contain the relevant disks, and then for each computer you could boot it with Clonezilla and back up the disk to an image file on the backup drive.

One benefit of this approach is that if you boot the computer using Clonezilla, you don't have to think about OS features like Volume Shadow Copy and the like; it doesn't matter which OS you use, as you are copying the data with the original OS shut down and in a stable state.

You mention not caring about being able to restore a complete image, but instead caring about the data / files on the disks.  Another option would be to use Clonezilla to copy partitions from the source disk to the destination disk, rather than storing them as images on the destination.

This approach will make the data more available, but will prevent you from taking advantage of the ability to compress the images to preserve more space on the backup disk (e.g. if you wanted to keep additional backup or other data on it).  That said, the remaining space on the disk should be available to create another partition for the other data you mention wanting to be able to store.

Answer (score 0):

If they're Windows machines and you'll want to browse the images through a Windows machine: use [Disk2Vhd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd). It can image a running system (via Volume Shadow Copy) and creates image files in a format that Windows can open without any additional tools.

> Nothing on the backup drive needs to be bootable or anything, so any special metadata partitions or anything that can't just be simply copied

*All* data that's on a disk can be copied – whether it's a partition or not, it's still just a series of 512-byte sectors on the disk. (Though, just because it is copied doesn't mean it would work – same as moving the actual disk to a different machine.)